# Possibly correct answer deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25346730/581205) might be wrong or right, but it shouldn't have been deleted. Assuming [the linked page](https://www.igvita.com/2014/05/20/script-injected-async-scripts-considered-harmful) is right and based on [mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script), combining `async` and `defer` may be exactly the right thing. Maybe just for some browsers or not at all, as the answer scores -3, but I wonder if the deleter knows any better.

IMHO this was a premature deletion, probably based on the length only, what do you think?

I see I did two things wrong:

- I missed the comment recommending the same
- I missed how old the question is (the OP doesn't care anymore)

My point was that deletions of answers based on how it looks like (it's terrible, I see) should be more careful *for the sake of the OP*, especially, when it's the only answer. But forget it, I was blind.

Comment: Even if that resolves the problem it should provide more detailed explanation such as "the problem is you're missing X and this causes Y and this in turn causes the behavior you observe. Doing Z will do that and that and solve your problem"

Comment: That was **not** an answer. *You should try X* is **at best** a comment. Where is the documentation? The explanation as to why the attribute would work?

Comment: Pretty sure that you are right.  However, posts like this are reviewed by other SO users.  Whom rarely check for technical accuracy, they go by how the answer *looks*.  It doesn't look good enough.  Hopefully he saw the comment, it is fairly unlikely.

Answer (score 8):

The OP posted the answer at 06:12. The answer was deleted at 08:37.
That means the OP has had **over 2 hours** to add some more information to the answer. Yet he didn't.

The answer was nothing more than *"Look at the manual, for subject X"*. That ain't a <sub>(good)</sub> answer. Heck, it doesn't even answer the question. As such, it was deleted.

The deletion was probably the result of a "First answer" review.

Comment: No doubt, the answer is of bad quality (though the documentation argument is [pretty weak](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=async+defer). **My point was that the OP was possibly denied a unique useful hint.** But I was blind as there has been already an equivalent comment. So the answer could rightfully be deleted "as a duplicate of this comment", but not for any other reason.

Comment: @maaartinus, granted, the answer could have been converted to a comment instead of simply being deleted, then again there already was a comment suggesting the use of `defer` under the question (predating the answer by several *months*).

Comment: I didn't even notice that the question was that old. I'm pretty sure the answer was deleted as a result of the review queue.
@maaartinus: What is the actual problem here? I really don't see it. Since it wasn't a _"Possibly correct answer"_, it appears this topic can be closed.

Comment: @Cerbrus Given that there's the comment there, the only problem is me being blind. Otherwise, there'd be a problem of deleting something of bad quality, but useful to the OP. While I like the full fledged answers on SO, sometimes a single word would be enough to saves me hours. The deletion should not be that robotized, especially when there are no other answers.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I didn't see that it's so old. Then the possible problem is rather non-existent as the OP doesn't give a damn anymore.

Comment: It was a _"user's first answer on a old question"_. That automatically enters in in the review queue. Enough people voted to delete the answer. That's not robotized, it's peer-reviewed.

Comment: @Cerbrus It's peer-reviewed, but sometimes the peers are (act as) robots. But forget it, this was a really bad example of this behavior because of the question's age and because of the comment.

Comment: Keep in mind that reviewers that aren't paying attention will get a slap on the wrist if they make too many bad reviews. Robo-reviewing is being punished ;-)